# access My Maps in android using apis

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can i access google my maps of respective users ( using google account ) from android using API ,
just like the goole map application on android is doing by clicking ***Layers -> More Layers -> My Map***

*Note : i don't want to let the use manually enter the url of saved my map into android*

example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are familiar with using the AccountManager on Android (see http://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/android-tutorial-snippetsauthenticating-accounts/ for a tutorial) you will need to use the Android `AccountManager`s [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) method with an authentication token type string set to `local`.

Comment: Well this is how i can get the authentication but how about getting My Maps from google ?

Comment: For that you need to work through http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html

Comment: as its been deprecated so is it safe to use it ? do i have any other alternative ?

Comment: can you just point me how i can get my maps details of users from these tables ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tutorial that was written specifically for that: the best you can do is look at the source code for MyTracks at http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/ and see how it accesses My Maps and Fusion Tables.

Comment: Well yes , After finding a source i came to know that MyTracks is using the same google map java library to fetch the My Maps. But for the newly released google map APIs there is nothing to get My Maps. its pretty disappointing